# Excel: Using index match to return the value underneath the searched value

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a table which looks like this basically:

`item  ----   item  ----   item-----   item`

location location location location

`item  ----   item  ----   item-----   item`

location location location location

etc

I have a different sheet which has the items sorted by the floor they are on (which i have done manually). now I would like to search the master table for the item and then return the location in the other sheet. I hope that makes sense?

EDIT:
[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BEfT.png)

I just realised I can attach a screenshot. So in my other Sheet I would like to search for the `ADS-09-01` and then return Level 9, etc etc for every item. my Index/Match formulas arent working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in cells `Sheet1!C2:F101` and the item you are searching for is in `Sheet2!A2`, try `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF('Sheet1'!C2:F101=A2,'Sheet1'!C3:F102,""))`.  If your version of Excel doesn't support dynamic arrays, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula.